# php - value of checkbox not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have this checkbox:

```
<label>Maintenance Mode: <small>Tick to enable/disable.</small></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="maintenance" value="1" <?php echo $maintenance; ?> >
```

I get the data from my database. So, if maintenance is enabled in my database, then the checkbox will be checked on. That happens like this:

```
if($sdata['maintenance']==1):
    $maintenance="checked='checked'";
else: 
    $maintenance="";
endif;
```

The problem is, whenever I want to disable maintenance, it doesn't update the database. It will still be set to "1".

This is how I post it:

```
$maintenance = inputFilter($_POST['maintenance']);
```

My database table have two columns:

`setting_name` and `setting_value`. In this case, it would be:

`maintenance` and `1`

I update it like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
  $value = inputFilter($value);
  mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET setting_value='$value' where setting_name='$key' limit 1")
  or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Whenever I uncheck the checkbox, and save the settings, nothing happens. I even tried to echp `$maintenance` from the post, and when it's unchecked, the value is 0.

Anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Webbrowser doesn't send checkbox in the POST request then is non-checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-checked checkboxes are not send in the POST request, so its key is not in $_POST

You should check if the checkbox name exists.

```
if(!isset($_POST['maintenance'])) {
     // Checkbox is unchecked
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this: `if(!isset($_POST['maintenance'])) {
                      $maintenance = 0;
                 }` .. still doesnt work.

Comment: Look at your loop, you are looping through $_POST and $_POST does not contain 'maintenance' key

Comment: I am not following. Sorry. Would you mind updating your answer, with your example?

Comment: Please try to understand what $_POST is and that you are doing a foreach on that variable and you don't have the 'maintenance' key there so it will never be modified on the database.

Comment: But I have other fields in my form, such as normal text inputs, and that works.

Comment: Because text fields are sent always, even if they are empty. Checkboxes are not sent if not checked. You can do a dirty trick but is very ugly: inside my if put $_POST['maintenance'] = 0;

Answer (score 0):

If an checkbox is unchecked it is not set in your $_POST. You have to check something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['maintenance']) && $_POST['maintanance'] != 0) {
    //is checked
} else {
    //is unchecked
}
```

Comment: @Alex-barroso beat me to it ;)

Comment: I tried this. If it was checked, I put hte $maintenance =  1 and if unchecked, $maintenance = 0. Didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    if($sdata['maintenance']==1):
        $maintenance="checked='checked'";
    else:
        $maintenance="";
    endif;
}
elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(array_key_exists('maintenance',$_POST)) {
        $maintenance="checked='checked'";
    }
    else{
        $maintenance="";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the default (off) value in hidden input before checkbox:

```
<input type="hidden" name="maintenance" value="0"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="maintenance" value="1" <?=($sdata['maintenance']==1 ? 'checked' : '')?> >
```